# Facebook Mobile Ad Blurry

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-quality

I'm having a strange problem with Facebook Ad designs in the Creative Hub. I reached out to Facebook several times with no luck and figured I'd tap into this community to see if anyone has experience designing these.

I am doing a 1080 x 1080 pixel ad and on mobile all of these ads are considerably blurry. I do not experience this with the Desktop versions, they are completely clear.

I have ensured the dimensions are correct (1080x1080) and have tried 2x and 3x of the dimensions with the same results. I understand Facebook quality is not the best but in this case it's completely unacceptable, all images on mobile that I upload are very blurry. I even experimented with actual photos instead of digital illustrations and I have experienced the same results. It's frustrating because I see crisp ads on Facebook all the time and I feel like I'm missing out on some kind of secret. For the record I am using Adobe Illustrator CC and using Export > Export for Screens for this example and when using photography I am using Photoshop CC Save For Web & Devices - they get the same results.

Any feedback and knowledge would be greatly appreciated.

**Desktop - Screenshot in Creative Hub (Clear)**

[image]

**Mobile - Screenshot in Creative Hub**

[image]

Comment: Hey, so odd thing is it is blurry on mobile website previews but it is crisp as expected on the Facebook mobile app! Its strange and I dont know why but I can 100% confirm this. I think it's because on the Facebook mobile website the image dimensions are clearly not 1:1 1080x1080 as they should be. My best recommendation ration is to download and check the mobile app for a true preview. If there is a way around the mobile website rendering those ads poorly, I'm not privy to that. Hope it helps!

Comment: Amazing you're right the full test did work fine, just the preview is blurry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to post an answer to my question to help others that are struggling.

I reached out to numerous professionals I know who were designers and Facebook content marketing specialists. I received different answers and after trying different advice I will tell you what worked for me:

- If you are viewing on the Facebook mobile website - these 1080x1080 ads will likely look blurry. Now view the same ads on the Facebook mobile app and they are clear and crisp. The Facebook Mobile Website seems to squish the images so they are not exactly 1080x1080 and that seems to be a contributing cause to the blur. So use the app for a accurate preview.
- No need to double the size of your canvas. This would give you 2160x2160 and Facebook actually won't take that dimension anyway, they will crop it. So 1080x1080 72DPI is fine.

Take Away: Keep it 1080x1080 72dpi Just like in the Facebook specifications and preview in Facebook mobile app. Hope this helps others!

Comment: you should now "accept" your answer so this shows as having been answered...

Comment: Ah, thought I did thank you. Updated.